# Why Angular code is not going in catch block if router.navigate is throwing the error?

Tags: angular, typescript

```
  try {
    this._router.navigate([result?.data?.menuLink]);
    console.log('inside try block');
  } catch {
    this._router.navigate(['/dashboards/analytics']);
    console.log('inside catch block'); 
  }
```

The `router.navigate` in try block is throwing error because that path does not exist but it is not going inside the catch block.

I am getting below error in console:

```
core.mjs:6469 ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'config/payment'
```

Comment: Because `navigate` _doesn't_ throw an error - read [the API docs](https://angular.io/api/router/Router#navigate).

Comment: I am getting this error in console - core.mjs:6469 ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'config/payment'

Comment: _"Uncaught (**in promise**): ..."_ which is why I suggested you read `navigate(...): Promise<boolean>`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [docs](https://angular.io/api/router/Router#navigate), the function returns a [Promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise). Promises are asynchronous, which means at the time when you are trying to catch the error, the error has not happened yet. Instead, you can use the [`.catch()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/catch) function on the promise.

```
this._router.navigate([result?.data?.menuLink])
  .catch(() => {
    this._router.navigate(['/dashboards/analytics']);
    console.log('inside catch block'); 
  })
```

Comment: Thanks this method resolves my problem

Answer (score 1):

just need set a syntax `async await` for catch promise error

```js
 constructor(private _router: Router) {
    this.catchRouteError()
  }
  async catchRouteError() {
    try {
     await this._router.navigate([result?.data?.menuLink]);
     console.log('inside try block');
   } catch {
     this._router.navigate(['/dashboards/analytics']);
     console.log('inside catch block'); 
   }
  }
```

But according to your code and description, you can set a specific component or use redirect config in your router for clean code

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'products',
    component: ProductsComponent
  },
  {
    path: 'cart',
    component: CartComponent
  },
  { path: '', redirectTo: '/products', pathMatch: 'full' },
  { path: '**', component: PageNotFoundComponent }
];
```